# SUBSTR() function in IF statement MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, substring

**Query:**

```
SELECT if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='substr(link,3), 'https://vimeo.com/'substr(link,3)) as link, `title`
FROM `video`
WHERE `reg_id` = '101'
```

In the above query I can't use `substr(link,3)` function when expression is `true`. After `v=` I wanna get a sub string value of `link` column in the table.

The above query fire some error. So please help me to solve this issue. Answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql you need to use the concat() function if you want to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', concat('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',substr(link,3)), concat('https://vimeo.com/',substr(link,3))) as link, `title`
FROM `video`
WHERE `reg_id` = '101'
```

Comment: @Shihas Consider marking an answer correct if it solved your problem.  This helps other users who are relying on your question for information.

Comment: All the above answers are correct only. In order to mark it Correct, I don't know which answer was posted first. As you are the one asked me to make it correct, I will mark your answer (Y) :D

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combing strings by writing them one after the other. You must use CONCAT function.

```
SELECT if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', CONCAT('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',substr(link,3)), CONCAT('https://vimeo.com/',substr(link,3))) as link, `title`
FROM `video`
WHERE `reg_id` = '101'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONCAT()` function to add the two strings together:

```
SELECT if(substr(link, 1, 2)='y_', CONCAT('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=',substr(link,3)), CONCAT('https://vimeo.com/',substr(link,3))) as link, `title`
FROM `video`
WHERE `reg_id` = '101'
```